# WSO2 API Manager: chpasswd.sh does not work when using external database

Tags: java, oracle, api, jdbc, wso2

When using the script ./chpasswd.sh to change the admin password, it reads all the jar files to setup a classpath. But it does NOT read the $CARBON_HOME/repository/components/lib/*.jar files. In this directory you put the ojdbc6.jar file when you use a database such as Oracle.

When I copy the ojdbc6.jar file into $CARBON_HOME/repository/lib directory, the script works.

My command is:

```
./chpasswd.sh --db-url "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl" --db-username wso2carbon -db-password wso2carbon --username admin --new-password nimda
```

Could this be a bug in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes..  I guess, according to the script,  you can see that it adds following directories as the class path.. It does not contains component/lib.  Also once `ant` script is run,  It may not copy the jars in component/lib in to repository/lib.

for f in "$CARBON_HOME"/lib/*.jar
do
  CARBON_CLASSPATH=$CARBON_CLASSPATH:$f
done

for g in "$CARBON_HOME"/repository/lib/*.jar
do
  CARBON_CLASSPATH=$CARBON_CLASSPATH:$g
done

for h in "$CARBON_HOME"/lib/api/*.jar
do
  CARBON_CLASSPATH=$CARBON_CLASSPATH:$h
done

Comment: Can someone from WSO2 pick this up and log this as a bug.