# Identity Server chpasswd.sh script not working with PostgreSQL database

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm receiving the following response while running the below command in my Identity Server /bin folder:

```
./chpasswd.sh --db-url "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wso2registry_db" --db-driver "org.postgresql.Driver"
```

> Database driver [org.postgresql.Driver] not found in classpath.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

References: 
[WSO2 API Manager: chpasswd.sh does not work when using external database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22200918/wso2-api-manager-chpasswd-sh-does-not-work-when-using-external-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the database driver jar to the **[CARBON_HOME]/lib** directory and try your command.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!